# google apps script invalid argument: searchPattern

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not sure what happened. My script was working fine but now I'm getting an invalid argument:searchPattern error on this:       `var rangeElement = copyBody.findText(email);`

```
function form(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');

  var email = e.values[1];

var docTemplate = 'yyyyyyyy';
var newEstimate = 'firstName' + 'lastName';
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(newEstimate).getId(); // Get document template, copy it, and save the Doc’s id
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);   // Open the temporary document
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(); // Get the document’s body section
  copyBody.replaceText('<Email>', email);

 var mailto = 'mailto:' + email; 
  var rangeElement = copyBody.findText(email);
  var startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
  var endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
  var text = rangeElement.getElement().asText();
  if (rangeElement.isPartial()) { text.setLinkUrl(startOffset,endOffset,mailto); } else { text.setLinkUrl(mailto); }
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the email look like when it fails?  Hint: It's in you document via  the replaceText() method.

Comment: It correctly makes a copy of the template doc and replaces the appropriate text and link ... but it also makes an additional copy of the template doc with nothing in place of the placeholder text: '<Email>' is empty ...

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is saying that your regex pattern "" is invalid.

If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) you can see that the syntax for this parameters needs to be supported by [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Try changing you to-be-replaced text with something like "[EMAIL]" instead.

Also, you might want to add error-checking if email is `null` or `""` so you don't perform invalid operations.

Comment: That seemed to work. Weird. I have code also replacing the address and don't get an error without the brackets. <shrug>. `var city = e.values[2]; var zip= e.values[3]; var address = city + zip; copyBody.replaceText('<address>', address);
  var replaceme = copyBody.findText(address);`